# Efeito de :hover num SVG dentro da tag <img>

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Eu tenho um arquivo `.svg` aqui e estou utilizando a tag `<img>` pra exibir este SVG na tela mas queria saber se tem como eu aplicar um efeito CSS nele como `:hover`, sem utilizar `jquery` de preferencia, já tentei usar o convencional tentando alterar as propriedades `fill` e `color` no CSS mas não consegui ter nenhuma alteração. Alguem pode me ajudar?

HTML:

```
<img src="assets/icons/diary.svg" class="img-svg mb-2" width="30" height="30">
```

CSS:

```
.img-svg {
    fill: red;
    color: green;
}
.img-svg:hover {
    fill: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Cara edite lá a resposta agora com a opção usando a tag IMG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isso, mas tem alguns detalhes.

Primeiro não use a tag `<img>`, use a tag `<svg>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc teria um arquivo `.svg` parecido com isso *(por estar em um `<symbol>` ele não vai aparecer na tela se vc abrir esse `.svg`, mas quando vc indexar no `.html` ele aparece)*

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >

  <symbol fill="var(--azul)" id="fish" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <path fill="var(--azul)" d="M98.5,47.5C96.5,45.5,81,35,62,35c-2.1,0-4.2,0.1-6.2,0.3L39,26c0,4.5,1.3,9,2.4,12.1C31.7,40.7,23.3,44,16,44L0,34
    c0,8,4,16,4,16s-4,8-4,16l16-10c7.3,0,15.7,3.3,25.4,5.9C40.3,65,39,69.5,39,74l16.8-9.3c2,0.2,4.1,0.3,6.2,0.3
    c19,0,34.5-10.5,36.5-12.5S100.5,49.5,98.5,47.5z M85.5,50c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5s2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5
    C88,48.9,86.9,50,85.5,50z"/>  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

Veja que no `<symbol>` eu já coloquei `fill="var(--azul)"` que eu vou usar para colocar a cor no elemento, e depois no `:hover` eu vou mudar o valor do `--azul`

E no seu `.html` vc vai ter isso.

```
<svg class="icon single"><use xlink:href="fish.svg#fish" /></svg>
```

Repare que aqui `xlink:href="fish.svg#fish"` eu chamo o ID so SYMBOL `<symbol id="fish"...`

Depois coloque a cor como variável, e depois faça o *override* da cor no `:hover`. Veja abaixo um exemplo.

```
:root {
    --azul: #0000ff;
}

svg:hover {
    --azul: #ffff00;
}
```

---

**Não consegui fazer funcionar aqui no Snippet do site.**

Mas aqui tem o link funcionando no GitHub: https://hugocsl.github.io/svg/

Esses são os arquivos que usei https://github.com/hugocsl/svg

---

**EDIT**

***Usando a tag `<img>`***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se o SVG já tiver alguma cor de `fill` vc pode usar um `filter` de `hue` para mudar a matriz de cor no `:hover` alterando a rotação do `hue`. Parece complicado, mas veja que o código é simples e pode resolver.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
.hov:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

```html
fazer hover aqui<br>
<img class="hov" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/adobe.svg" alt="">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, na vdd oque acontece é que eu meio q ja faço isso que vc explicou só que usando uma biblioteca que achei la no npm, estou utilizando Angular 7 ai estou utilizando uma biblioteca q me ajuda a manipular SVG's, só que essa biblioteca nn se da muito bem com CSS ai eu descobri (sou iniciante como frontend) que da pra usa o SVG na tag <img>, <iframe> e <object> e estava em busca de uma solução pra esse meu problema mas parece que vou ter q continuar com aqela biblioteca. Mas mto obrigado msmo assim por gastar um pouco do seu tempo para esta resposta!

Comment: @BrunoEduardo sem problemas meu caro, eu tb já passei por esse problema, por isso tinha a resposta para ela rss. Mas resumidamente, usando a tag <img> vc não vai conseguir trocar a cor do SVG, a não seu com gambiarras usando Filter. Vou fazer um teste com essa opção e se funcionar eu atualizo aqui e te aviso.

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta.